# How can I run a .class file through Intellij IDEA API?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am creating a plugin which should compile a java code, run it on input that I provide from a file, and then save the output to another file, but I am unable to figure out a way to do this.

For compilation, I got help from [sbmpost's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5394382/sbmpost) code for his plugin.

Can someone please help me with how to run the file on some input, and store its output?

Answer (score 0):

Check [JavaScratchConfiguration](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/fecd2910aee084520b2d16694f3237cd9914cee7/java/execution/impl/src/com/intellij/execution/scratch/JavaScratchConfiguration.java#L47-L47) and [JavaScratchCompilationSupport](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/64acbb3482700ca0930aa8dff4d1c22165fab92f/java/execution/impl/src/com/intellij/execution/scratch/JavaScratchCompilationSupport.java#L48-L48). These are used to compile and run Java Scratch files in IntelliJ IDEA.